# CUDA events order

Tags: cuda

I have a problem concerning cuda events and asynchron computation and i am not sure when an event is fired in that case (pseudocode):

```
cudaStream_t oStream;
cudaEvent_t oEvent;
cudaStreamCreate( &oStream);
cudaEventCreate( &oEvent);
MyKernel1<<<..,..,.., oStream>>>();
cudaEventRecord( oStream, oEvent);
MyKernel2<<<..,..,.., oStream>>>();
cudaEventSynchronize( oEvent );
```

Is `oEvent` fired after `MyKernel1` or after `MyKernel2`, which means when does the host starts processing again after `cudaEventSynchronize`? (for sure in that example `MyKernel1` is not finished when my `MyKernel2` call was done on host)

Comment: I do not understand the sentence _for sure in that example `MyKernel1` is not finished when my `MyKernel2` call was done on host_, since `MyKernel1` and `MyKernel2` belong to the same stream. The documentation on `cudaEventSynchronize()` says that it waits until the completion of all device work preceding the most recent call to `cudaEventRecord()`. I would say that you cannot tell if `oEvent` is fired before or after completing `MyKernel2`, but that for sure it is fired following the completion of `MyKernel1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oEvent` "fires" (is completed) after `MyKernel1()` is completed (and before `MyKernel2()` begins execution).

The kernel executions are serialized because they are issued to the same stream.
Issuing kernel launches to a stream and `cudaEventRecord` to a stream should all be asynchronous.

The `cudaEventSynchronize()` statement will cause the host thread to pause until `oEvent` is completed, and then allow the host thread to continue.  This means the host thread could continue while `MyKernel2` is executing, but not while `MyKernel1` is executing.

Comment: That means that you cannot predict if `oEvent` is fired while `MyKernel2` is still running or not, right?

Comment: If `MyKernel2` is running, `oEvent` "has fired" (is completed).  You can asynchronously discover the completion status of an event using `cudaEventQuery` from host code.